# How to get the value of the input text box using the blazor template

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I've got a textbox in the template column. And how do I get the value of the text box by clicking the button. This is my code.Here I add a new value based on the text  box value.

```
 <tr>
                        <td>

                        <Template>
                            @{ var ctx = (context as sampleData);}
                               

                          <input  type="text" @bind-value="@CurrentValue" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" />
                                @{ if (ctx.Name !=null)
                                    {
                                        <input  type="button" OnClick="((e) => NewItem(e))">Add new</input>
                                    }
                                }

                            
                        </Template>
                        </td>
                        </tr>

                        public void newItem(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.MouseEventArgs args)
                          {
                              /// based on textbox value  i will add new value
                          }
```

Comment: Where do you put the button and text box, can you share some code?

Comment: Which `template column` ? Can you post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)